# Please tell how to create the counter in excel based on the below details

Tags: excel, counter, nested-for-loop

how to create the counter in excel with cell reference of rows for example:

```
Col_A   Col_B     Counter 
r1      1a            1
r2      1b            2
r3      2a            1 
r4      2b            2
r5      2c            3
```

Please advise the solution in excel ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a weird question, because you already have the counter in `col_B`: the second character defines it: "a"=1, "b"=2, "c"=3, ...

So you need two things:

- You need to read that character (which is the most far right character), you can do that using the `=Right(B1,1)` function.
- Then you need to translate that character into a number: "a" being 1, and so on. For that, you might use the `=CODE(C1)` function, and from that, you subtract 96 (as small letters start at 97 in ASCII coding). However, this makes your idea case sensitive, so I would advise you to use the `=UPPER()` function first and subtract 64 from that (as capitals start at 65 in ASCII coding).

Have fun!

Comment: if inside col_B there is no a, b, c and long text is there then how we can make the counter in the next column like row 1 = 1, row 2 = 2, row3 =3?

Comment: @asharhabib: that's extremely difficult: imagine you have "a1", "a2", ..., then that's easy to split into "a" and "1", "a" and "2", ..., but what if you have "a1b2", do you need to split it into "a" and "1b2" or into "a1b" and "2"?